# GWT Dynamic MenuItem-List

Tags: java, gwt, menuitem

I need to crate a dynamic list from a String List and use the List-items as a MenuItem Entry. Is this possible like with a loop over the complete list and then

```
new MenuItem(list-entry, new Command(){} )
```

After that i want to select it like a checkbox (just the usage not an actual checkbox).
Is my thinking progress reasonable or do i need to rethink everything? grateful for any help, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can loop on it

```
MenuBar mymenubar = new MenuBar(true);
            for(final String string : myListOfStrings){

                MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem(string , new Command() {
                    @Override
                    public void execute() {
                         //Do some thing on each menu
                    }
                });

                mymenubar .addItem(menuItem);
            }
```

Selecting like a checkbox(on menu items) is not a good idea.In menu you can select one menu item only at a time.